# Create a new variable in R, when at least one of the the current variables has a specific value(s)

Tags: r

I would like to create a new variable "index".

For each of the variables A-F, the possibles values are 0(no),1 (active),2(inactive), and N/A.

If at lease one of the A, B, C, D, E, F has the value = 1 or 2, then the new variable index = 1. Otherwise index = 0.

I have tried to use "mutate", and not sure how to make this happen when there are multiple variables. Could someone please help?

df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),A=c(0,1,0,0,N/A,1),B=c(1,0,N/A,1,0,0),C=c(0,1,0,0,1,0),D=c(2,0,0,0,1,0),E=c(0,0,0,0,2,N/A), F=c(N/A,N/A,N/A,0,1,1))

The output will look like

index = 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1

Thanks! I really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `if_any` to loop over the columns 'A' to 'F', check if the columns have values 1, or 2 with `%in%`, and convert the logical column to binary with `as.integer` or `+`.  `if_any` returns TRUE only if any of the columns for a particular row have 1 or 2 or else FALSE

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(flag = +(if_any(A:F, ~ .x %in% c(1, 2))))
```

-output

```
> df
   ID   A   B C D   E   F flag
1  1   0   1 0 0   0 N/A    1
2  2   1   0 1 0   0 N/A    1
3  3   0 N/A 0 0   0 N/A    0
4  4   0   1 0 0   0   0    1
5  5 N/A   0 1 1   0   1    1
6  6   1   0 0 0 N/A   1    1
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom! That works on my rest of the data set. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tom, I have one more question. If all variables A~F has missing values N/A, I would like to see the output = N/A instead 0. Now it gave me 0 for this case. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @Ellie I would converrt `"N/A"` to `NA` i.e. `df %>% na_if("N/A")  %>% mutate(flag  = case_when(if_any(A:F, complete.cases)~ +(if_any(A:F, ~ .x %in% c(1, 2)))))`